# ASP web.config path -> cannot load file

Tags: asp.net, path, web-config, asp.net-membership

I try to use asp:login with my own membershipprovider, but when I write this code I got problem with type, concretly I get error that I am not able to load ~/App_Data/MyMembershipProvider
    `<membership defaultProvider="default">

      <providers>

        <clear/>

      <add name="default" type="/~App_Data/MyMembershipProvider"/>

      </providers>

    </membership>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type needs to be of the format Namespace.ClassName.
You might have to deploy the assembly to the GAC or in the bin folder and then provide the type as CustomNamespace.CustomMembershipProvider

Comment: I am not using any namespace there. I created project and in my classes it doesnt show any namespace

Comment: Then just push in the ClassName in the type

Comment: Check this article: http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/

Comment: if you mean this I tryed it as well  
<add name="default" type="MyMembershipProvider"/>

Comment: hope that this: cannot make that error   <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>

Comment: thats just an appsetting key, whose value may or may not be used in the code. whats the new error that you are getting? is it cannot load classname, if yes then do you have the assembly (dll) deployed in the GAC or in the bin folder?